# React Router v4 routes not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am relatively new to reacts and I'm trying to figure out how to get React router to work. I've got a super simple test app that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, IndexRoute, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <h1><Link to= "/about">Click Me</Link></h1>
const About = () => <h1>About Us</h1>

const Test = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
    <Route path ="/" component = {Home} />
    <Route path ="/about" component = {About} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

when I run the app the home component loads without any trouble, and when I click the "Click Me" link the url changes to localhost/about, however nothing happens. If I click refresh I get a "Cannot GET /about." Clearly I am doing something wrong but I haven't been able to figure out what. I am also using Webpack.

Comment: Are there any messages in the console? It may be an issue with the `About` component and not the router itself. Also, try to put the `About` component on the */* path to see what happens.

Comment: RE: Cannot GET /about: Consider using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It's facebook blessed and makes the server part of this work out of the box in development, among many other development niceties. Without it you need to manage routing everything to index.html yourself, or use the hash router in react-router.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to use an exact path for `/` otherwise it will also match `/about`.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

As mentioned in the comments, for something this simple I would suggest using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which will make sure your server code and your webpack settings are all correct. Once you use `create-react-app` you'll just need to use `npm` to install the react router v4 package, and then put your code above into the `App.js` file and it should work. There are some small changes to your code to get it to work with `create-react-app` as can be seen below:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <h1><Link to="/about">Click Me</Link></h1>
const About = () => <h1>About Us</h1>

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

export default App;
```

The [quick start instructions from React Router V4 documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) will tell you pretty much the same as I just explained.

Comment: Um excuse me but I'm having a similar issue although I've added exact and its still not working

Comment: @akshaykishore You should open a new question and give us the code you are using that will reproduce your problem.

Comment: The code is similar except I'm importing the components from an another file. By the way on refreshing the second page component is rendered .

Answer (score 37):

If you're running from localhost you need to add historyApiFallback: true to your webpack.config file

Comment: This was my issue!! Thank you.

Comment: A bit more info around this would be really helpful!

Comment: how do you implement this if usign create-react-app? and is it an issue if your stack is deployed to a public server?  I get the same issues both local and on my server

Comment: This needs to be added to docs, I would have never known this.  Been pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: i dont have a webpack.config file. What should i do?

Comment: @AshishKirodian if you are using react scripts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files

Comment: Thanks, spent a whole day finding my issue.

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for

Comment: I had the same issue. I added this in my webpack.config (I wanted to add a little precision):

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

Answer (score 10):

if Adding `exact` Don't resolve issue, i have replaced this with

```
  <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
```

This one

```
  <Route exact path="/"> <App /> </Route>
  <Route path="/login"> <Login /> </Route>
  <Route path="/register"> <Register /> </Route>
```

putting component as Route Child solves my page routing i hope it helps someone else too

Comment: This broke my app unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

While using **Switch** we need to keep in mind that we specify the *routes* to be from *most specific* to *most generic*.
In your case, you have specified `"/"` before `"/about"`.
So every time react is looking for `"/about"` but going down `<Route "/"` satisfies for `"/about"` as well (because `"/about"` is sub-route of `"/"`)
So use: **"/about"** before **"/"**

This way you can omit *exact* as well

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, IndexRoute, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <h1><Link to= "/about">Click Me</Link></h1>
const About = () => <h1>About Us</h1>

const Test = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path ="/about" component = {About} />
        <Route path ="/" component = {Home} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also solve this issue by keeping the default Route always at the end

`<Route path ="/about" component = {About} />`

`<Route path="/" component={Home} />`  // Always at the end

No need to put `exact` keyword

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it can help someone. I forgot to use the proper history, instead of using the `Router` I was using the `BrowserRouter` which ignores the property `history={...}` to use its own. I was trying to redirect the page with my manually created history but `BrowserRouter` was using its own one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way this can happen. It is a stupid mistake but that was the issue in my case.

My problem was an import error. Initially, I had the following import :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I decided to move the BrowserRouter component to a higher level but while removing the no longer user Router component, my imports became like this :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

So, effectively, I ended up removing the Switch component and aliasing BrowserRouter as Switch.

It was normal that Switch was no longer working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

App.js

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes , Route, Link, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/"  element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
      <Route path="/dashboard"  element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Dashboard.js

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Router V6 and you set your route as:

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

change it to use element:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of this is not working, then you can try this,
I also had the same issue with React Router. I am using React Router V6 and I solved it by enclosing the Route in a Routes tag,

- A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then enclose it Routes tag

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path ="/about" component = {About} />
        <Route path ="/" component = {Home} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

By adding the Routes tag it solved my issue. Hope it was helpful.