# where is create-react-app webpack config and files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I create a ReactJS project with the `create-react-app` package and that worked well, but I cannot find webpack files and configurations.

How does react-create-app work with webpack? Where are the webpack configuration files located in a default installation with `create-react-app`? I'm unable to find configuration files in my project's folders.

I have not created an override config file. I can manage config settings with other articles but I want to find the conventional config file(s).

Answer (score 220):

If you want to find webpack files and configurations go to your package.json file and look for **scripts**

[image: img]

You will find that scripts object is using a library **react-scripts**

Now go to node_modules and look for react-scripts folder [react-script-in-node-modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Grrn.png)

This **react-scripts/scripts** and **react-scripts/config** folder contains all the webpack configurations.

Comment: I saw but i have not react-scripts dir

Comment: I just created an app using create-react-app and in my case there is a folder  react-scripts in node_modules. can you share your package.json

Comment: **This answer is no longer correct**, NPM is now *flat* meaning all the modules are on the root `node_modules` directory

Comment: The actual webpack config is here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

Comment: The most common use case would be to customize the project's webpack config. But if it is in node_modules it will be overwritten in every npm install, won't it?

Comment: That's correct, if you update any code in node_modules and do npm install, your changes are gone. So we should avoid updating the node_modules code. But as you mentioned there are use cases where you want to updated the configuration sitting in your node modules. 

In case of CRA, there is a module called customize-cra which allows you to do that
https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra

Comment: @Blanc That's why you should clone CRA, modify whatever you want, and use your own version instead of the official one, if you want this configuration changed. It's their policy decision to not let users make changes to the webpack configuration. You either have to eject and do everything yourself, or clone CRA as I said.

Comment: you can also use [craco](https://craco.js.org/docs/) to override CRA configurations without ejecting it

Answer (score 155):

The files are located in your `node_modules/react-scripts` folder:

Webpack config:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

Start Script:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

Build Script:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/build.js

Test Script:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js

and so on ...

Now, the purpose of CRA is not to worry about these.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#get-started-immediately):

> You don’t need to install or configure tools like Webpack or Babel.
> They are preconfigured and hidden so that you can focus on the code.

If you want to have access to the config files, you need to [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) by running:

```
npm run eject
```

> Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!

In most scenarios, it is best not to eject and try to find a way to make it work for you in another way.

If you need to override some of the config options, you can have a look at https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco

Comment: I know these are hidden, but i wanna know where are these and how react-create-app handle this ability ?

Comment: Then you will probably have to look at the source code. I am not sure

Comment: @Mohammad checkout the source for 'react-scripts' you can find all the config there

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but helped me regardless

Comment: Looks like Craco is currently having some issues with create-react-app 5.  They've been working on patching this since January, but 5 months later and still not quite done https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/378

Comment: Craco is the way to go. It provides overrides for webpack, babel, eslint and others withou the need to eject [https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/getting-started/](https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/getting-started/) . Issues also solved for CRA5 [https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/426#issuecomment-1307319525](https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/426#issuecomment-1307319525).

Answer (score 68):

A lot of people come to this page with the goal of finding the webpack config and files in order to add their own configuration to them. Another way to achieve this without running `npm run eject` is to use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). This allows you to overwrite your webpack config file without ejecting.

Comment: Is it still the preferred solution? There is this warning on rewired project: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#rewire-your-app- 
: 
"As of Create React App 2.0 this repo is "lightly" maintained mostly by the community at this point. ... Note: I personally use next.js or Razzle which both support custom Webpack out of the box."

Comment: @AnthonyKong thanks for this update, the situation is really bad... central upstream discussion appears to be at: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6303

Answer (score 45):

Assuming you don't want to eject and you just want to look at the config you will find them in `/node_modules/react-scripts/config`

```
webpack.config.dev.js. //used by `npm start`
webpack.config.prod.js //used by `npm run build`
```

Answer (score 29):

Webpack config used by `create-react-app` is here:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/config

Comment: There's a lot going on in that canned webpack.config.js. Imagine trying to build that up from scratch!

Comment: @AndrewFielden imagine when it doesn't do what you expect and you have to dig into it !

Answer (score 12):

You can find it inside the **/config** folder.

When you eject you get a message like:

```
 Adding /config/webpack.config.dev.js to the project
 Adding /config/webpack.config.prod.js to the project
```

Answer (score 10):

Webpack configuration is being handled by [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts).
You can find all webpack config inside node_modules **react-scripts/config**.

And If you want to customize webpack config, you can follow this [customize-webpack-config](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc)

Comment: The instructions at the link labeled `customize-webpack-config` depend on `react-app-rewired`, which is mostly unmaintained according to its [GitHub README](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#readme).

Answer (score 7):

Ejecting is not the best option as well as editing something under `node_modules`.
`react-app-rewired` is not maintained and has the warning:

> ...you now "own" the configs. No support will be provided. Proceed
> with caution...

Solution - [use craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco).

Comment: craco does not work with react-scripts 5.

Comment: @tutiplain do you know a tool that works with cra 5?

Comment: @JanisJansen I do not. I needed this because my project uses some LESS that is embedded somewhere deep in node_modules. I ended up using the less compiler directly and embedding the resulting stylesheet directly in the react code.

Answer (score 4):

Try ejecting the config files, by running:

```
npm run eject
```

then you'll find a config folder created in your project. You will find your webpack config files init.

Comment: Be aware that this is a major step that you can't easily come back from. This would be a pretty drastic solution to getting rid of a warning.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `create-react-app` with `craco`, and I was able to override my webpack configuration when updating to webpack 5 with the `craco.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [
            require('tailwindcss'),
            require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
        },
    },
    webpack: {
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
            webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
                fs: false,
            };
            return webpackConfig;
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late, but for future people stumbling upon this issue, if you want to have access to the webpack config of CRA, there's no other way except you have to run:

```
$ npm run eject
```

However, with ejection, you'll strip away yourself from CRA pipeline of updates, therefore from the point of ejection, you have to maintain it yourself.

I have come across this issue many times, and therefore I've created a template for react apps which have most of the same config as CRA, but also additional perks (like styled-components, jest unit test, Travis ci for deployments, prettier, ESLint, etc...) to make the maintenance easier. Check out the [repo](https://github.com/TheCapedBaldi/pureact).

Comment: Craco works well. There are other that do similar things. So, there IS another way for a lot of scenarios.

Comment: Link to repo is broken.