# Create-React-App - Any way to use webpack babel loaders on specific node-modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a shared ui-library as a private node_module. In my angular apps I have a webpack configuration that lets me transpile these components as they're included. 

`{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        // Don't attempt to transpile any non-@aver node-modules
        exclude: /(node_modules\/(?!(@aver)\/).*|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ng-annotate-loader',
            options: { add: true, single_quotes: true }
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
              retainLines: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },`

When I tried to include parts of this shared library in my new react app (created from `create-react-app`), It told me I need to use loaders to include those components. But with create-react-app you don't have access to the webpack config directly. So I think one of two things needs to happen:

1. Find a way to override the wepback config to allow it to use loaders on my particular node_modules. I'd like to avoid `ejecting` if possible.
2. Compile my shared library ahead of time to a dist file that I can include which is already transpiled. I don't like this because it means I have to include the entire shared library versus the individual components that I actually need.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files

Comment: @SashaKos I'd REALLY like to not eject if possible. Which is what I'm really asking about how to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where is create-react-app webpack config and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files)

Comment: Hey, I put an answer in the duplicate post about using react-app-rewired to not eject - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52768121/3107798