# React and turn.js (turn is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, turn.js

I want to run turn.js with react. I found an example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/005xlk45mn

I adapted the code to my project, but i get the following error: 
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).turn is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
import "turn.js";

const options = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  autoCenter: true,
  display: "double",
  acceleration: true,
  elevation: 50,
  gradients: !$.isTouch,
  when: {
    turned: function(e, page) {
      console.log("Current view: ", $(this).turn("view"));
    }
  }
};

class xxx extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $("#flipbook").turn(options);
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div id="flipbook">
                    <div className="hard">Turn.js</div>
                    <div className="hard"></div>
                    <div> Page 1 </div>
                    <div> Page 2 </div>
                    <div className="hard"></div>
                    <div className="hard"></div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Condolences;
```

this also didnt work:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
componentDidMount() {
        $(this.el).turn();
    }
render() {
        return (
                <div id="flipbook" ref={ el => this.el = el }>
                    <div className="hard">Turn.js</div>
                    <div className="hard"></div>
                    <div> Page 1 </div>
                    <div> Page 2 </div>
                    <div className="hard"></div>
                    <div className="hard"></div>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: i need help guys :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... and I solved using a lower version of jQuery like the `npm` description says

> Latest version uses jQuery 1.12.0 because jQuery 3.x was breaking the
>   page flipper.

use JQuery version `1.12.0` and it works

I even made a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-turnjs-flip-magazine-vri0e) using React 16.10.x

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the turn.js plugin is not being attached to your instance of jQuery.  This is likely related to your webpack setup.  As you noted, the code works fine in codesandbox.

In order to install itself as a jQuery plugin, turn.js needs to modify a global jQuery object.  Try using [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) in your webpack config so that jQuery is exposed to turn.js.  Perhaps something like this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery'
})
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. i created the app with npx react-create-app and can't find a webpack config

Comment: `react-create-app` hides the webpack config. You can apparently expose it via `npm run eject` (irreversible) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files or by using `react-app-rewired` https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc