# Link tags for CSS using Webpack 4.41

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I have created a basic application using `Create React App`. I came across different methods to load link tags to HTML while surfing on the internet.

Currently, WebPack is creating link tags as:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I want link tags to be rendered in a different form such as:

```
<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="style">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></noscript>
```

Is there any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you built the project using `create-react-app`, then you won't find a customizable `webpack.config.js` (there's one, but it's handled by `react-scripts`).

[According to Dan](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/460#issuecomment-240704595), they don't allow customization of plugins to minimize potential issues.

So, if you want to add a plugin to a react app that was bootstrapped with `create-react-app`. You'll have to run `npm run eject` and this will make all the configurations files available for manual customization.

Once you ejected the project, you can preload resources for Webpack using the `preload-webpack-plugin`. Details [here](https://github.com/googlechromelabs/preload-webpack-plugin)

Basic example `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'My Cool App',
    template: './app/index.html'
  }),
  new PreloadWebpackPlugin()
]
```

That should preload the assets and dependencies automatically for you. Additional usage details [here](https://github.com/googlechromelabs/preload-webpack-plugin#usage)

Comment: Getting error as `Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-before-html-processing'. Hook was not found.` I am using `"preload-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0"`. I checked for the solution to upgrade it to `3.0.0-beta.3` but upgrading to that keeps the link tag same.

Comment: Because you started the project with `create-react-app` the Webpack configuration is handled by `react-scripts`. Take a look at [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395804/where-is-create-react-app-webpack-config-and-files)

Comment: Also, it seems [somebody customized the configuration of a project built using `create-react-app`](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc), it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have already ejected the project. Also, they are using `react-app-rewired` which I am not using. I am working with `create-react-app` directly. On top of that, I am not very sure about how adding `copy-webpack-plugin` can help in this scenario.