# Lost source mappings in browser's console in a create-react-app project converted to typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, winston

So I have a standard react project created with the last version of create-react-app

Recently I moved it to typescript following the documentation [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) and started modifying some of the files to move them to ts/tsx.

Well now, after running `npm start`, on the browser console **every** single one of my log messages generated by `winston`, which were before showing the correct source file that generated them, are now showed by the browser console as being generated from a file called `BrowserConsole.ts:29`. I have no idea what this file is, I suppose it is some react build generated file?
Anyway what I need is to have back the correct mapping so I know which file is printing which log messages, as it was before adding typescript to the project.

I already tried all the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161196/chrome-devtools-not-showing-correct-file-name) in the first answer (except the one which requires ejecting because I REALLY don't want to do that) without success.

As requested I add below the package.json and tsconfig.json of the project (note that I cannot modify most of the parameters on the last one because they get anyway instantly overwritten by the react scripts of create-react-app as soon as I run `npm start`)

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "cra",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.39",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.12.4",
    "@types/openlayers": "^4.6.16",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/web3": "^1.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "change-case": "^4.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-alpha.25",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "formik-material-ui": "3.0.1",
    "i18next": "^17.0.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^3.0.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "mdi-material-ui": "^6.22.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multihashes": "^0.4.19",
    "notistack": "^1.0.9",
    "ol": "^5.3.2",
    "qrcode.react": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-country-flag": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-geolocated": "^3.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^10.7.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.5.2",
    "react-qr-reader": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-sizes": "^2.0.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.13.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4",
    "web3": "^1.2.4",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-transport-browserconsole": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.* > sourcemap.html",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/md5": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/qrcode.react": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/react-qr-reader": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.9",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "lorem-ipsum": "^1.0.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "size-limit": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to create a new CRA project and add TS there and it shows me correct file names. Could you provide more details about your setup such as versions of installed packages, tsconfig.json file, and any other configuration you have?

Comment: @Shlang added config files as requested, I don't see anything strange in them even comparing those to the one generated after creating a new create-react-app project with typescript included

Comment: I see `winston-transport-browserconsole` in your dependency list and I guess that BrowserConsole mentioned in the question is a part of this package. Do you log the messages using `winston` and not simply `console.log`? Could you provide an example of code that produces a message with incorrect file names?

Comment: @Shlang you are right, it seems that the `console.log` messages are correctly mapped, those generated by `winston` are not. I missed them because the latter were far more. The problem still persists, before typescript the winston logs were correctly mapped to the app source files, after typescript introduction they are **all** mapped to that winston file. I even tried removing the `browserconsole` third party transport protocol and configuring winston to use the core `console` protocol but now all those messages are just mapped on a winston `console.js` file.

Comment: It seems that while it is [technically possible to have a custom logger that would print a correct file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815640/a-proper-wrapper-for-console-log-with-correct-line-number), such a feature [was never implemented in winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/200). So I don't think switching a CRA app to TS had any impact on this.