# How to polylfill Buffer for jsonwebtoken in Wepack 5

Tags: jwt, buffer, webpack-5

I am upgrading to Webpack 5 and I have an issue with the package jsonwebtoken (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) that needs Buffer (at https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/sign.js#L91)
Since Webpack 5 polyfills are not included for nodejs functions and wen I try to use the function `sign` from jsonwebtoken it throws the following error :

```
message: "Buffer is not defined"
stack: "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined↵    
at module.exports (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:91:26)↵
```

To solve the issue I installed https://github.com/feross/buffer with

```
npm install buffer
```

and in my webpack config I added

```
 resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "Buffer": require.resolve('buffer/'),
    }
```

or

```
 resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "buffer": require.resolve('buffer/'),
    }
```

I also tried

```
 resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "buffer": require.resolve('buffer/').Buffer,
    }
```

But this last one produce a Webpack schema error :

```
 configuration.resolve.fallback['Buffer'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string, ...] | false | non-empty string
      -> New request.
      Details:
       * configuration.resolve.fallback['Buffer'] should be an array:
         [non-empty string, ...]
         -> Multiple alternative requests.
       * configuration.resolve.fallback['Buffer'] should be false.
         -> Ignore request (replace with empty module).
       * configuration.resolve.fallback['Buffer'] should be a non-empty string.
         -> New request.
    at validate (/home/ant1/packcity/front-pmd/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:104:11)
```

Despite my trials it is not working and the error persists.

Did someone succeed in adding the polyfill for Buffer in their app bundled with Webpack ?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved my issue by adding

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    }),
```

As suggested here https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/3369#issuecomment-721975183

Comment: Where do you add this? package.json?

Comment: In my Webpack config : webpack.base.babel.js

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when having a similar issue with Gatsby. To fix, I added:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                Buffer: [require.resolve("buffer/"), "Buffer"],
            }),
        ]
    }
}
```

to my `gatsby-node.js` config.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it this way in Gatsby. I didn't have to install the `buffer` dependency. Just added this to my `gatsby-node.js` file.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, stage, plugins }) => {
    if (stage === 'build-javascript' || stage === 'develop') {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
            plugins: [plugins.provide({ Buffer: ['buffer/', 'Buffer'] })]
        });
    }
};
```