# Override some Webpack 5 NodeJS modules with polyfill

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-5

I have NodeJS code that I now need to move to an embedded system.  It takes far too long to simply start NodeJS ("Hello World" ~11sec on a BeagleBone Black) so we needed an alternative.  The IoT.js looks promising but it does not support some of the internal NodeJS modules (e.g. url, zlib, tty)--which my code needs.  I am using Webpack 5.35.0 to create a single file for my code but this is where my problems lie.  I want to use Webpack with a `node` target since IoT.js offers most of what node offers natively.  However is there a way to force Webpack to use polyfills for some of the modules? For example, `browserify-zlib` instead of expecting nodes `zlib`.

My basic Webpack configuration is simple:

```
{ target: 'node10.17',
  entry: './index.js',
  output:
   { filename:      'index.js',
     path:          '/work/proj/dist',
     libraryTarget: 'umd' },
  stats: 'errors-only',
  resolve:
   { modules:    [ '/work/proj/node_modules' ],
     extensions: [ '.js', '.json' ],
   }
}
```

I have done some reading where people claim adding a simple `resolve.fallback.zlib = false` and `resolve.alias` should do the trick--which is not working for me.

I tried to simply add `resolve.fallback.zlib = false` in the hopes to just have zlib omitted from the Webpacked output and this did not work.  No matter what I do the standard Webpack boilerplate "node" zlib include code exists.

Standard Webpack boilerplate when using `node` target.

```
/***/ "zlib":
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** external "zlib" ***!
  \***********************/
/***/ ((module) => {

"use strict";
module.exports = require("zlib");;

/***/ })
```

Other things I tried were--**ALL** of which did not work:

I was hoping this would alias zlib and actually put in the `browserify-zlib` code.

```
resolve:
   { modules:    [ '/work/proj/node_modules' ],
     extensions: [ '.js', '.json' ],
     alias:      { zlib: '/work/proj/node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/index.js' },
     fallback:   {} } }
```

Same as the previous example but thought by disabling the fallback the alias/polyfill would go into the output.  This is what others online had success with.

```
resolve:
   { modules:    [ '/work/proj/node_modules' ],
     extensions: [ '.js', '.json' ],
     alias:      { zlib: '/work/proj/node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/index.js' },
     fallback:   { zlib: false } } }
```

Here I just hoped to not include zlib to see if Webpack would omit it with a `node` target.

```
resolve:
   { modules:    [ '/work/proj/node_modules' ],
     extensions: [ '.js', '.json' ],
     fallback:   { zlib: false } } }
```

Lastly I tried to use  the plugin `node-polyfill-webpack-plugin` but with the `node` target it does not seem to do anything.  If I chose a `web` target the plugin seems to work as I'd expect (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5)). Again, I'd prefer a `node` target so it uses native modules and the setup seems cleaner; but maybe this is the only approach. If this is the approach then how to support `fs` and other non-browser modules that IoT.js supports natively?

```
...
plugins = [ new NodePolyfillPlugin({ excludeAliases: [] }) ];
```

It seems that when the `node` target is selected there is no way to override any of the default/boilerplate code added to the output file.  Does anyone have experience with IoT.js and Webpack, or overriding the default Webpack 5 code for `node` and use a polyfill instead?  Not sure if a Webpack plugin is an approach.  I am a little new to Webpack.  Could this be a problem with Webpack?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am in the same boat: I am using es2019 as my target and want to run the compiled bundle in QuickJS, which is lacking some built-in modules that I need polyfilled.

Comment: I realize this is very late for a response, I apologize. I was never able to find a solution to the problem. Since IoT.js was so limiting (among other issues) I had to abandon the idea of using IoT.js on my embedded project and had to rewrite the application in C--very unfortunate.