# webpack 5 angular polyfill for node.js crypto-js

Tags: angular, webpack, config

I have basic question about webpack 5 configuration since I have zero experience with it. I would like to create most simple Angular application that uses *node.js* module *crypto-js* and *SHA256*.

Before webpack 5 it was quite simple. You didn't have to worry about webpack, it was somewhere in behind.

In command prompt I did :
ng new TestApp -> cd TestApp -> npm install crypto-js -> npm install --save @types/crypto-js -> write simple test code with imported SHA256 -> build it and -> it worked!

Now I get message:

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no >longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty >module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

I have to install this module and include this polyfill inside config file.
The question is howto write most simple webpack.config.js, where to put it and what to include in it besides these lines?

BR

Answer (score 38):

I had the same issue, this is the working solution i found on git hub.
https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4070

run in your project directory:

```
npm install crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify
```

tsconfig.json
Add this in:"compilerOptions": { [...] }

```
"paths" : {
      "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
      "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
      "assert": ["./node_modules/assert"],
      "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],
      "https": ["./node_modules/https-browserify"],
      "os": ["./node_modules/os-browserify"],
    }
```

Comment: After 2 days of hunting, this solved my issue of no crypto using Angular 12, trying to validate AWS Cognito JWT without running a separate node server.  Thank you so so much

Comment: This worked for me too with everything but crypto. My package `@toruslabs/eccrypto` depends on it and I guess doesn't see the override. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem with bcryptjs package and Angular 13. This solved the warning. I also had to add `"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["crypto"]` to angular.json like it's explained in Wahib Kerkeni reply

Answer (score 37):

I ran into this problem after upgrading to Angular 12, so after searching I ended up doing the following:

In **tsconfig.json** I added:

```json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "paths":{
          "crypto":["node_modules/crypto-js"]
        }
     }
    }
```

And in **angular.json** I added:

```json
     {
    "architect": {
            "build": {
              "options": {
                "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["crypto"], // note that this is the key of --> "crypto":["node_modules/crypto-js"]"
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the warnings are gone.
I hope this will help you out.

Comment: You are a Crack! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. In the `allowedCommonJsDependencies` I had to call it `crypto-js` because that is the node module I load in.

Comment: I had to use

 **"stream": [
      "../node_modules/stream-browserify"
    ]**, 
Notice the two dots.. because I use  "src" as baseUrl

Comment: I've had a similar problem with "stream". First I tried the above solution with `"stream":["node_modules/readable-stream"]`, which didn't work out. I even though about trying the custom webpack for Angular, but then I tried `"stream":["node_modules/stream-browserify"]` and it did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The below steps will help resolve this problem

- Install the `browserify` ports for `crypto` and `stream`

  ```
  npm install crypto-browserify stream-browserify
  ```
- In `tsconfig.json` under compiler options, add the below lines. Since `webpack` is not auto-exporting the polyfills, these specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations.

  ```
  "paths":{
  "crypto":["node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
  "stream":["node_modules/stream-browserify"]
  }
  ```
- In `angular.json` under `architect->build->options` add the below line which says the CommonJS packages `crypto` should be used without a build time warning.

  ```
  "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["crypto"]
  ```

<sup>**Note** : Read what [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) does.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Nicolas 's answer, I also had a problem the 'Global is undefined'.

To solve that I had to add those lines to 'polyfills.ts' :

```
(window as any).global = window; 
(window as any).process = {
   env: {DEBUG: undefined},
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, the webpack configuration is hidden by Angular that only give you access to some options exposed by the AngularCli.

However you can use the package [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) that works very well. It's easy to use and you can substitute some webpack options without breaking all the configuration provided by Angular.

So, in your case, you could add a [crypto-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify) as fallback for "crypto". In that case your webpack extra config file would look like :

{ resolve: {
fallback: {
crypto: "./node_modules/crypto-browserify"
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, but my stupid mistake might save someone tonnes of time. I accidentally imported router from express instead of from angular in a component. Cost me 3 days and a migraine.

So check that you haven't accidentally imported node modules into your angular components, same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825110/11395562)

Comment: thanks mate, I was thinking the same your answer justified it

Answer (score -1):

If you are in vue and your error starts like this 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' ...' installing `url-loader` will do the trick. Just install it using npm. `npm install --save-dev url-loader`