# Problem with polyfills, crypto and angular

Tags: angular, webpack, cryptography

I'm using Angular and I've just added a library to my main project, so I went to package.json, added

```
"@lo/lib-common-mylib": "^0.0.250"
```

did an npm install and I had no problem so far.

When I go into my component and wrote

```
import {utils} from '@lo/lib-common-mylib';
```

I still have no problem, but as soon as I go in the constructor and wrote

```
private regionalHelper: utils.RegionalHelper
```

I receive this error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

I have crypto installed in the common-lib imported, but unlike the others questions similar to this, I don't have webpack installed, so I have no webpack.config.js; and mainly I'm working on Angular, not on React.

I've tried to follow these steps: [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20819#)

like installing path-browserify and add it into tsconfig, but it's not working.

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572355/webpack-5-angular-polyfill-for-node-js-crypto-js/67808287#67808287

Comment: Thank you, but I've already try it, and it doesn't work for me.