# Angular 14 Webpack 5 error, unnecessary nodejs modules (I think) are preventing me from serving application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I am working in a brand new Angular 14 application. My node version is v14.20.0,
npm is 8.17.0

I'm not sure why, but for some reason I have all of these nodejs dependencies included. I've tried deleting node_modules and npm installing again, but I still run into this issue.

I've tried a number of solutions I saw online for this issue, but I can't seem to outrun this bug.

How can I find and remove the package(s) that is requiring all of these dependencies?
below is the initial error that I saw, and it occurred for a number of different packages.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }

This error appeared for a number of different dependencies. I was able to resolve the errors in my terminal by installing via npm, and then adding these paths to my tscongfig.json

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
"paths": { 
  "path": [ "./node_modules/path-browserify" ],
  "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
  "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],    
  "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
  "zlib": ["./node_modules/browserify-zlib"]
}
```

This solved the Webpack 5 errors in the terminal. However, when I went observe the application in the browser, I saw two more errors.

```
capability.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
 at 2942 (capability.js:1:28)
 at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)

util.js:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
 at 74 (util.js:109:1)
```

I resolved them by adding the below code to my polyfills.ts file

```
import 'zone.js';  // Included with Angular CLI.

(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = { env: { DEBUG: undefined }, };
```

now I am getting this error in the chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
 at 8606 (response.js:43:45)
```

I think that the answer is to just not import whatever package contains all of these dependencies, but I don't know how to locate and remove it.

If anyone has any insight into this it would be greatly appreciated.

I would post screenshots, but my rep isn't high enough yet. If you need more information please ask.

Thank you

Comment: Try checking out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808287/12291279

Answer (score 2):

I also suddenly got so many dependencies issues though I didn't change anything as such. The code was working fine before. Then I realized that I imported Router module from wrong package. Instead of importing `Router` from `angular-router`, I accidently imported it from `express` :|

```
import { Router } from 'express'; // wrong import
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; // right import
```