# Angular 14 to 15 Migration: can't resolve 'crypto'

Tags: angular, webpack, cryptojs

When trying to migrate from Angular 14 to 15 we found the next issue after doing a `ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15` and running ng serve:

```
./node_modules/asmcrypto.js/asmcrypto.all.es8.js:3572:23-40 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\projects\ms-front\node_modules\asmcrypto.js'

    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
            - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
            - install 'crypto-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
            resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

I read somewhere that we should modify the **webpack.config** file but our project doesn't have such a file.

Note that **crypto-browserify** is indeed a dependency of my project and it is already downloaded in node_modules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack 5 angular polyfill for node.js crypto-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572355/webpack-5-angular-polyfill-for-node-js-crypto-js)

Comment: @JSONDerulo I tried the answers provided in that thread but neither modifying tsconfig.json and angular.json neither installing crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify with the tsconfig.json modifications did work