# i tried to Polyfill modules in webpack 5 but not working (Reactjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, moralis

Hi guys am a newbie in React when i start my project i get the Wepback V5 Error Message

**Resolve updated** : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756#issuecomment-1001162736

**This What am using!**

```
Os: Win11
Node : v16
React:v17
React-script : v5
Webpack:v5
```

**This Error Message Contains**

```
Crypto
Http
Https
Stream
```

**Error Output**

Compiled with problems:X

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Portfolio\portfolio_app\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Portfolio\portfolio_app\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Portfolio\portfolio_app\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

**Image Contain Output**

[image: Webpack5 Error Message]

Comment: No one answerd that

Comment: I have the same issue, and try fixing with many suggest solutions, but not work for me

Comment: the best way I found is to rewire the app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085181/import-web3-into-react-js-getting-breaking-change-webpack-5-used-to-incl

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I resolve these errors but my app did not render.
If you are interested to clear these errors you can paste code right into `your-project/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` but these changes can be overwritten after rebuilding your app.
Find in  module.exports object resolve and write fallback,in your case it's "crypto": `require.resolve("crypto-browserify")`.

And install dependency `npm install crypto-browserify`.

```
resolve: {
//   fallback: {
//     "fs": false,
//     "tls": false,
//     "net": false,
//     "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
//     "https": false,
//     "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") ,
//     "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
//     "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
//     "util": require.resolve("util/"),
       "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
}
```

Or you can add fallback using react-app-rewired as was described in Github https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756
Install react-app-rewired, create `config-overrides.js` file in the root of your project.
My code in the file

```js
module.exports = function override (config, env) {
    console.log('override')
    let loaders = config.resolve
    loaders.fallback = {
        "fs": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "https": false,
        "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") ,
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "util": require.resolve("util/"),
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
    }
    
    return config
}
```

In package.json change scripts from
`'start': 'react-scripts start'`
to
`'start': 'react-app-rewired start'`.
Then start project npm run start or yarn start

Comment: Thanks Bro u deserve an upvote

Comment: react-app-rewired: command not found

Comment: @rsc05 did you install the " npm install react-app-rewired" dependency?
Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired

Comment: I am getting this error: `Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /my-project/node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Any idea how to resolve? thanks

Comment: Messing around with node_modules is a bad idea... I don't know how you plan on deploying anywhere.

Comment: @rsc05 you need to use "npm i react-app-rewired" to use this

Comment: Thank you, I've seen numerous answers on this issue but only yours really helped in my case cuz I couldn't find the correct webpack.config.js to address these fallbacks. I was trying to add it next to tsconfig.json (I'm using Typescript) but it didn't help, so making changes to node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js really solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 20):

I solved my issue like this:

```
npm uninstall react-scripts
npm install react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Comment: thank you. this was a clean solve for me.

Comment: this solved my issue, but now the project can be built. npm run build fails..

Answer (score 14):

To use polyfill in webpack 5 in reactjs
Follow the below steps:

1. First Install `npm install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin` module.(reference link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin)
2. Then go to follow webpack.config.js --> node-module -> react-scripts -> config -> webpack.config.js
3. Then add below code:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me with `react@18.2.0` and `react-scripts@5.0.1`. Many thanks

Comment: webpack.config.js file not present in my react project

Comment: unfortunately this won't work. Also not sure if this package is supported by the author.

Comment: You can create the webpack.config.js manuallY

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a new issue with many packages including web3 as these are not compatible with Webpack v5 without adding fallbacks for the polyfils.

Issue noted here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756

I solved this issue by adding the fallback to my webpack.config.js file;

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            assert: require.resolve('assert'),
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
            https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
            os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        },
    },
};
```

but also need but got compilation errors on the build process:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error
```

this was resolved by adding to my .env file;

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I came across the same fallback hints given by the react error messages and I added the exact code to `\project-root\webpack.config.js` but I don't believe react is reading my custom `webpack.config.js`. How did you get react to read the custom config?

Comment: I also have the same problem with react-scripts reading the `webpack.config.js` file.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is to using `Craco` module to override the Webpack ModuleScopePlugin and resolving it to use browser-compatible modules.

> You can also use `react-app-rewire` module.

Add other Node.js modules to the `require.resolve` field if you need.

1. Install modules

```
yarn add @craco/craco crypto-browserify path-browserify stream-browserify -D
```

2. Add `craco.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: webpackConfig => {
      const scopePluginIndex = webpackConfig.resolve.plugins.findIndex(
        ({ constructor }) => constructor && constructor.name === 'ModuleScopePlugin'
      );

      webpackConfig.resolve.plugins.splice(scopePluginIndex, 1);
      webpackConfig['resolve'] = {
        fallback: {
          path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
          crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        },
      }
      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

3. Replace scripts fields in `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build",
  "test": "craco test",
  "eject": "craco eject"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have enough reputation to *edit* or *comment* on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71803628/13086873), I had to create a new answer that works for me. Basically one would also need to install `readline`.

Namely:

```
npm uninstall react-scripts
npm install react-scripts@4.0.3
npm install readline
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case a not used component importing led to the error. Simply remove unwanted component imported.

> import {ReactDOM} from "React"

Comment: After I tried all the proposed solutions, I read your comment, and something clicked! These errors had apparently come out of the blue, and in the end, I found that I had an 
` import { config } from "dotenv"; ` not used! I removed it, cleaned my modules, reinstalled and everything works.

Comment: For the record, none of the proposed solutions worked for me.  ( node18.12.1 , "react": "18.2.0")