# Webpack 5 No Polyfills and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

My Intial Problem was that webpack 5 doesnt have polyfills so I had to find a way to solve that.

I used the second solution on this link to solve that problem: [i tried to Polyfill modules in webpack 5 but not working (Reactjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398678/i-tried-to-polyfill-modules-in-webpack-5-but-not-working-reactjs)

I did:

```
npm install react-app-rewired
```

and I changed the package.json start script to:

```
'start': 'react-app-rewired start'
```

then I created the config.overide.js file:

```
module.exports = function override (config, env) {
  console.log('override');

  let loaders = config.resolve;
  loaders.fallback = {
    "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
    "util": require.resolve("util"),
    "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3"),
    "url": require.resolve("url/"),
    "fs": false,
};


return config;};
```

This solved my polyfill errors but now i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at Object../node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:42:1)
at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at Module../src/screens/LoginScreen.js (HomeScreen.js:46:1)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at Module../src/App.js (bundle.js:24:78)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

I have a feeling that this error is comming from me trying to overide webpack.
my github: https://github.com/ilanhk/MERN-Ecommerce-Template