# Error: nodebuffer is not supported by this platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geojson, shapefile, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use Shpjs package for import Shape file on leaflet map
based on the shpjs doc : [shpjs](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js)

Here is my code :

```
      const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState(null); //state
      //onChange function
      const onChangeFile = ({ target }) => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file = target.files[0];
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      reader.onload = function (buffer) {
        setGeoData(buffer.target.result);
      };
    };
```

and after that i use shpjs package like this :

```
 const geoJson =  await shp(geoData)
```

after import shp.zip i get this error : [image: Error]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should put the error as text for better reference. A minimal reproducible example is also preferable

Answer (score 0):

you can use npm package
`const  NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');`
and in react node modules config file and in webpackconfig add the package above
[refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398678/i-tried-to-polyfill-modules-in-webpack-5-but-not-working-reactjs)   jay patel author