When I am deploying my React application on Cloudflare it gives me the error
Title: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto' in Webpack 5 with Create React App"
Description:
I'm working on a React application created with Create React App, and during the build process, I'm encountering the following error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for Node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case.

--> build the project  this command npm run build
--> then deploy the dist  folder  to the server

for reference check this  link
https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/framework-guides/deploy-a-react-site/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/70398678
