# Using Playfab SDK with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, sdk, playfab

I am trying to use Playfab SDK on my React project, but no success yet..

I can't find well explained documentation for it.

- created a react app with:

```
npx create-react-app playfabtest
```

- installing PlayFab SDK for nodejs:

  npm install playfab-sdk

**NOTE**:  ( there is another SDK for JavaScript (`npm install playfab-web-sdk`), but I am assuming that for a react app, the nodes is the correct one ?)

[The documentation for those SDK](https://github.com/PlayFab/NodeSDK)

- Modified the `App.js` file on the project with this code:
  (tried in many ways actually, I put the last one tried that didn't work neither).

---

App.js:

```js
// import { PlayFabClient } from './playfab-sdk/Scripts/PlayFab/PlayFabClient';

// var PlayFabClient = require('./PlayFabSdk/Scripts/PlayFab/PlayFabClient.js')

function App() {
  const PlayFabClient = require('./PlayFabSdk/Scripts/PlayFab/PlayFabClient.js');

  PlayFabClient.settings.titleId = '';
  PlayFabClient.settings.developerSecretKey = '';

  PlayFabClient.GetTitleData({ Keys: ['Sample'] }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Got an error: ', error);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Reply: ', result);
  });

  return ...
}
```

---

- After that, if I run :  npm start

get this error :

---

error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/PlayFabSdk/Scripts/PlayFab/PlayFab.js 4:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'D:\Github\playfabtest\src\PlayFabSdk\Scripts\PlayFab'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:     resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./src/PlayFabSdk/Scripts/PlayFab/PlayFab.js 6:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'D:\Github\playfabtest\src\PlayFabSdk\Scripts\PlayFab'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
```

---

Would be very helpful if can explain how to make PlayfabSDK run well on a react app.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Create React App, you need to use [ES6 style `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement instead of `require` to import the [playfab-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/playfab-sdk) NPM package into your project.  Also you need to set the settings on the `PlayFab` object instead of the `PlayFabClient`.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PlayFab, PlayFabClient } from 'playfab-sdk'

PlayFab.settings.titleId = process.env.REACT_APP_PLAYFAB_TITLE_ID || ''
PlayFab.settings.developerSecretKey = process.env.REACT_APP_PLAYFAB_DEVELOPER_SECRET_KEY

// continue with component implementation
const App {
  // get title data
  PlayFabClient.GetTitleData(...)
  // etc...
}

export default App
```

Comment: Following all these steps, i still got the error :
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/playfab-sdk/Scripts/PlayFab/PlayFab.js 2:10-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'D:\Github\playfabtest\node_modules\playfab-sdk\Scripts\PlayFab'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it..
etc..

Comment: The "Module not found" error you are describing is related to the specific version of the JavaScript bundler itself (Webpack 5), it is not an error in the PlayFab SDK. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5