# Where to find 'webpack.config.js' - BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following errors on my browser concerning webpack5.

[image]

I have located answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5) but the authors are directing to a file called 'webpack.config.js' which apparently exists in the root folder of my app.  The problem is, I cannot find such a file in the root folder of my app.  Please can someone advise?

Answer (score 0):

You likely can't see the config file because you built your app using create-react-app so configuration is managed for you. Try installing stream-browserify `npm install stream-browserify`

You could also use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco which allows you to keep react bundled up but also gives you access to change webpack configuration.

The last option would be to downgrade.