# Syntax in crac-webpack-rewired to solve webpack polyfills error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I created my project in React using create-react-app, but after sometime I got to this error in the console

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack \< 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
\- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
\- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
@ ./node_modules/loader-utils/lib/index.js 7:25-54
@ ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js 11:19-42
@ ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js 3:15-33
@ ./src/App.js 13:0-35
@ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5), I reached the conclusion I had to modify the webpack.config.js that I did not have because I created the project with create-react-app. Instead of ejecting (it is not very recommended), I used the npm package advised at the end of [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6303). The problem is that there are no examples on how to use it. My question is which syntaxis do I have to follow to modify config/webpack.extend.js? This is the code at the moment:

```js
module.exports = {
    dev: (config) => {
        //override webpack configuration
        config.externals =[..];
        return config;
    },
    prod: (config) => {
        //override webpack configuration
        config.externals =[..];
        return config;
    }
};
```

I have tried using console.log(config) but it never gets to print as errors are printed back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `console.log()` because that code is not executed from the browser, but in the Webpack "compilation" phase.

This could be a possible solution for your case.

```js
module.exports = {
    dev: (config) => {
      //override webpack configuration
      config.resolve.fallback = {"path": require.resolve("path-browserify")};
      return config;
    },
    prod: (config) => {
      //override webpack configuration
      config.resolve.fallback = {"path": require.resolve("path-browserify")};       
      return config;
    }
}
```

Notice that you have to install the package `path-browserfy`.

You can also set the `path` property to false.