# Unable to polyfill node modules webpack 5

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, webpack-5

I get several of the following errors for various packages when I run 'npm start'

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js 27:16-32

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\gaxios\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
```

I've multiple fixes discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5) including downgrading react-scripts to version 4 (which breaks my site), setting empty module fallbacks, and trying to use the node-polyfill-webpack-plugin but none have worked.
Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          fs: false,
          tls: false,
          net: false,
          path: false,
          zlib: false,
          http: false,
          https: false,
          stream: false,
          crypto: false,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [new NodePolyfillPlugin()],
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the full error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js 27:16-32

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\gaxios\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 20:24-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 22:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 26:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 28:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js 22:15-32

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node/crypto.js 20:15-32

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\crypto\node'
Did you mean './crypto'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js 14:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\google-p12-pem\build\src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js 14:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\gtoken\build\src'


ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js 20:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\gtoken\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js 45:30-44

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist'


ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js 47:30-44

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist'


ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 5:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\jwa'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js 8:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js 8:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\TheBlitzingBolt\Desktop\mcna-awards-website\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```