# How to polyfill in webpack v5 to be able to use fs in react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, fs, webpack-5

I've tried a lot of things so far and I've been able to compile after installing and including some polyfills for util, constants, os, etc. in my webpack.config file but I'm still getting a "process: module not found" error after installing and including a resolve.require for process.

Comment: try the second highest answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556946/11931524

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.