# Which webpack.config.js do I modify to resolve fallbacks

Tags: reactjs, webpack, polyfills, webpack-5

Webpack 5 does NOT include polyfills for node_modules by default.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5) says to modify webpack.config.js with the suggestions from the error messages.

My question is, which one?

```
(yt-fork-env) ryanjsfx@MB-145 pitch-v5 % find . -name webpack.config.js

./node_modules/istanbul-reports/lib/html-spa/webpack.config.js 
./node_modules/number-to-bn/internals/webpack/webpack.config.js 
./node_modules/ethjs-unit/internals/webpack/webpack.config.js 
./node_modules/oboe/webpack.config.js 
./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js 
./node_modules/@motionone/dom/webpack.config.js 
./node_modules/aos/webpack.config.js
```

I started out by modifying the one in react-scripts but it just totally ignored a fallback I added. I guess I could write a script to add fallbacks to all of them...but it'd be nice to know if I could just add fallbacks to one of them (and how to determine that).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, any of them work, I just had to hard reload (Cntrl-C and then `npm run start` again).