# react js npm googleapis,@googleapi/sheets package error for version (npm=9.2.0,node=v18.13.0)

Tags: npm, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer, google-api-javascript-client

[React message error image links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ypk.png)

My local PC is running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

When installing the package, there are no problems; there are a few warnings and a red error, but rendering works fine. But when I installed the Google package "npm install googleapis" or "npm install @googleapis/sheets" and imported the function, errors occurred. I commented on the import package line, and there is no error. to make sure, I uncommented the line again but errors(long 50 errors package) happen

--more detail about my pc [optional]--

I use Ubuntu, and when I install "sudo apt install npm," it downloads a far-old version "12.x.x." Then I remove it with apt autoremove and download the node file from the website, version 18.13.0. At the time, I'm not sure how to install the file, so I extract the node file, rename it to node, move it to /opt, and export it to $PATH:.../opt/node/bin. (if you don't mind please tell me how to install node properly)

I'm not sure what the cause of the error is.

Thank you for helping

Simon

Expect to understand the error to fix the core problem if there is a bad PC system configuration.

Comment: I create new react app and import only googleapis package and there is 50 errors and 49 warnings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5  this may help me in the future

Comment: Did you start react and npm install  googleapis , import it to your app() project? if you did, Is there an error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)