# How do I fix jsonwebtoken Can't resolve 'buffer'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, jwt

I am still a beginner in ReactJS and MERN stack as a whole. The `Activate.js` code below basically means when the `useEffect()` hook runs, we will have the `jwt token` that was taken from the `route parameter/url` using the `{match}` props. We decode the token to get the `name`. Finally, the `name` and `token` will be used to save it back in the state - `useState({})`

**Activate.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../core/Layout';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';

const Activate = ({match}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    token: '',
    show: true
  }); // values is an object while setValues is a function

  let paramsToken = useParams(); // useParams replaced match.params.id on react-router-dom 6

  useEffect(() => {
    // let token = match.params.token; // obsolete
    let token = paramsToken;
    let { name } = jwt.decode(token); // destructure to get the name,

    if (token) {
      setValues({...values, name, token});
    }

  }, []);

  const { name, token, show } = values; // destructure

  const clickSubmit = event => {
    // code snippet
  };

  const activationLink = () => (
    <div>
      <h1 className="p-5 text-center">Hey {name}, Ready to activate your account?</h1>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={clickSubmit}>Activate Account</button>
    </div>
  ); // used parenthesis so we don't use the return keyword

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <ToastContainer />
        {/* {JSON.stringify({name, email, password})}*/} {/* We can use this to know the value in the state */}
        {activationLink()}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Activate;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

**Problem:** The problem I am currently facing with `jsonwebtoken` package is that I am prompted with 2-3 errors and I have indicated those errors below. Please take note that I am following a tutorial and the tutorial's code is for 3 years ago and my latest node.js version and other packages are installed as of March 2023.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in
> 'C:\Users\john\Documents\node-projects\react\mern-ultimate-authentication\mern-auth-client\node_modules\buffer-equal-constant-time'
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> 'C:\Users\john\Documents\node-projects\react\mern-ultimate-authentication\mern-auth-client\node_modules\jsonwebtoken'
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> 'C:\Users\john\Documents\node-projects\react\mern-ultimate-authentication\mern-auth-client\node_modules\jsonwebtoken'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default....

Do you know how to solve the issue above? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5 see if this takes anywhere

Comment: @cmgchess Ah Yes. Thank you for that link. I'm gonna take a look and try to solve the issue on my end too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use `jwt.decode()` i think you should import the package :

```
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

or if you want to use `jwt.verify()`
like this :

```js
jwt.verify(yourToken,yourJWTKey,callbackfunction(error,userData){
  // your code here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to try it.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by using the package that you recommended. I will also provide the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by using the `jwt-decode` package as recommended by another stackoverflow user.

For those who are looking for the correct answer, I have included the updated code below.

**Activate.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../core/Layout';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';

const Activate = ({match}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    token: '',
    show: true
  }); // values is an object while setValues is a function

  let paramsToken = useParams(); // useParams replaced match.params.id on react-router-dom 6

  useEffect(() => {
    // let token = match.params.token; // obsolete
    let token = paramsToken;
    // we don't need to type token.name if we destructure it
    let { name } = jwt_decode(JSON.stringify(token)); // jwt_decode() requires the token to be converted into string first

    if (token) {
      setValues({...values, name, token});
    }
  }, []);

  const { name, token, show } = values; // destructure

  const clickSubmit = event => {
    // code snippet
  };

  const activationLink = () => (
    <div>
      <h1 className="p-5 text-center">Hey {name}, Ready to activate your account?</h1>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={clickSubmit}>Activate Account</button>
    </div>
  ); // used parenthesis so we don't use the return keyword

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <ToastContainer />
        {/* {JSON.stringify({name, email, password})}*/} {/* We can use this to know the value in the state */}
        {activationLink()}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Activate;
```

Comment: I was able to use this code as a reference to solve this problem. Thanks!