# google-auth-library has missing dependencies when installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to use [google-auth-library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest) with a react app but am getting various errors which seem to indicate missing dependencies. The errors are all in a format similar to this:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/private/tmp/minimal-example/node_modules/buffer-equal-constant-time'
```

The error messages include details on how to add a polyfill for the missing dependencies, but even after going through and adding all these polyfills I am unable to use the library. The logs for the development server still show errors for missing files, and the browser console has the following error:

```
GET http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Node 16.13.2
2. Create a react app `npx create-react-app minimal-example`
3. Enter directory for the created project `cd minimal-example`
4. Install google-auth-library `npm install google-auth-library --save`
5. Add the following code to `./src/App.js`
   `const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');`
6. Start the development server `npm start`
7. Observe errors

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem with same `google-auth-library` package!

This is a problem with using webpack 5 on  `React scripts=> v5`

Have three solutions to resolve:

1. downgrade `react-scripts` to version `4.0.3`. on `package.json` file.
2. Overwrite the config webpack config, but, i will need install [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to do this, because react app not have `webpack.config` on tree app files.
3. you can eject the script to root folder executing `npm run eject`, but caution, this action is permanent, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48395890

Some people answered this problem in [How to Polyfill node core modules in webpack 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5)
and https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12072