# React-Router <Switch> seem to have no effect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Router>
        <Switch> 
          <Route path="/auth">
            <Auth></Auth>
          </Route>
          <Container>
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/load" component={Load} />
          </Container>
          <Route>
            <Redirect to="/sign-in"></Redirect>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

`<Container>` is a context provider.

```
export const Container = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element[] }) => {
    return <AuthContainer.Provider>
        <DataContainer.Provider>
            {children}
        </DataContainer.Provider>
    </AuthContainer.Provider>
}
```

when location is in `/`, the `<Redirect>` have no effect.
changing `<Route>`to`<Route path="/" exact>` have no effect in `/`,either .
Please tell me the reason, thank you.

**I move the `<Container>` to the out of `<Switch>`,thing go to be correct.but why?**

Comment: What is happening right now? Please provide more details. Also, we may need to see relevant contents of `Container`. If it matches the base path "/" then you will likely never get to your redirect...

Comment: I guess you need to use `exact` path. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456656/react-router-v4-routes-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Switch will look for exact match, so you need to define the path prop for your route, or else it is never going to match any of the routes.

```
<Route path="/">
   <Redirect to="/sign-in"></Redirect>
</Route>
```