# Why is react router not displaying the required element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Chat from './Chat';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__body">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Sidebar/>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <h1>This is home screen</h1>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/rooms/:roomId">
              <Chat/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code is showing the sidebar properly..But its neither displaying 'This is home screen' on default home page nor the  component when I change url to room/someid..According toz [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456656/react-router-v4-routes-not-working) I even added exact before the path. Why is Route not working?

Comment: Have you tried moving the Sidebar *outside* the Switch? The point of a Switch is to only render one of its children.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe that solved the problem